# Implementing images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fiddling around with JS and made a random word generator (foodinator) for practicing purposes. How can I implement images with this?
Dish 1 should always show with Image 1, Dish 2 with Image 2 and so on.

HTML (index.html)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">
        <h1><u>What are you going to eat?</u></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="foodDisplay">
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button onclick="newFood()">
            New Dish!
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript (scripts.js)

```
var foods = [
'Dish 1',
'Dish 2',
'Dish 3',
'Dish 4',
'Dish 5',
'Dish 6',
'Dish 7',
'Dish 8',
'Dish 9',
'Dish 10'
];

function newFood() {
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (foods.length));
document.getElementById('foodDisplay').innerHTML = foods[randomNumber];
}
```

When clicking the button it picks a random dish from the list, that works. I expect it to show up with the correct image.
I know it is very basic knowledge, I hope some one can direct me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What images are you talking about? There are only strings in your code, no images.

Comment: Yes indeed sorry, let me clarify. I only need the code which puts the images with the correct strings. I am adding the actual images later.

Answer (score 1):

Tip: Make an object which will have the both values like a ( key & value ) structure.

```
var foods = [
{name: 'Dish 1', image: 'image_dish_1.jpg'},
.
.
.
];
```

Need a bit modify in our function: ( ES6 )

```
function newFood() {
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (foods.length));
var food = foods[randomNumber];
document.getElementById('foodDisplay').innerHTML = `
      <img alt="${food.name}" src="${food.image}" />
    `;
}
```

Need a bit modify in our function: ( ES5 )

```
function newFood() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (foods.length));
  var food = foods[randomNumber];
  var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
  imgElement.src = food.image;
  imgElement.alt = food.name;
  document.getElementById('foodDisplay').innerHTML = imgElement.outerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Your last code snippet doesn't work, `imgElement.innerHTML` is the empty string. I guess you meant to empty the display div and then `document.getElementById('foodDisplay').appendChild(imgElement);`?

Comment: Try outerHTML or something over images doesn't work properly

Answer (score 0):

I used a placeholder for the path of the image, but you can change it to your case. It should give you an idea of how to insert an image in your `div`.

```js
var foods = [
  'Dish 1',
  'Dish 2',
  'Dish 3',
  'Dish 4',
  'Dish 5',
  'Dish 6',
  'Dish 7',
  'Dish 8',
  'Dish 9',
  'Dish 10'
];

function newFood() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (foods.length));
  var img = '<img src="//lorempixel.com/400/200/food/' + foods[randomNumber] + '/" alt="' + foods[randomNumber] + '">';
  document.getElementById('foodDisplay').innerHTML = img;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    <h1><u>What are you going to eat?</u></h1>
  </div>
  <div id="foodDisplay"></div>
  <div class="button">
    <button onclick="newFood()">
      New Dish!
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```